# Subtheme template not being read

Tags: theming

Good Day All, I need some guidance please.

I have a `page.tpl.php` file in `sites/all/themes/mysubtheme/templates` but it is not reading that file (override), it is still looking at the default `page.tpl.php` in `sites/all/themes/bootstrap-less-master/templates`.

Any way how I can change this or what can be done to fix this?

Comment: Hey hey, welcome to DA. I edited your question slightly, are you OK with the changes? Is the info still right? At least that's the way how it's supposed to be. If not, please update your question to clarify. Next things I want to know: Have you enabled your sub-theme AND set as default? Have you flushed caches after you put the template into the sub-theme's template folder?

Comment: @leymannx yes it looks great, thank you. I flush the cache after each change / file location change. It is set as the default. I am using the bootstrap theme as a base

Comment: How do you know it's not reading it, have you changed something obvious? How exactly have you flushed cache? Try CLI or through Performance page.